# Use a webpage as a screen saver

Tags: fullscreen, webpage

We have a number of retail stores that sell laptops. There are a number of display models on show in each retail store. At the moment screen savers are used to promote different offers and these screen savers are out of date.

What I would like to do is open up a browser on these machines and just use a webpage. This way I can control exactly what is displayed and keep it up to date with our latest offers.

Is it possible to have the webpage in full screen mode, with no address bar or tabs visible.

As far as I'm aware these are Windows machines, probably running Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you know the so called "kiosk-mode" of the InternetExplorer?

Just pres F11 when you opened the Page you intended to show. The Website is shown in Fullscreen (until you press F11 again). Just tested with an Win 7 and IE9 and it still works (feature exists since IE6 or 7 i guess)

Comment: Ha ha thanks Wegus, thats perfect. I was completely over thinking this.

Comment: Problem is that the browser has to be manually launched, and won't reset itself like a screensaver would.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who wants to do this, but feels a full-screen browser window doesn't meet their needs:

https://github.com/cwc/web-page-screensaver/releases

Comment: how can i use it? i have never compiled anything in .net

Answer (score 4):

How about this.

Code up a .NET Windows Forms application, put a [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx) on it (setting Anchor to Top, Bottom, Left, Right), make it the same size as the form, and set the start page as appropriate.

Compile it. Rename it from MyApplication.exe to MyApplication.scr.

Put it in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Select it as the current screensaver in Display Properties.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the cheapest solution is to click F11 and disconnect the keyboard and the mouse from the computer. Every browser will do you that work (Chrome, FF, IE)..

Comment: They are laptops...